# trace measurable operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Hello,

I have a question about trace measurable operators and I think it's not a hard one. However, I'm quite confused because I cannot prove it.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a semi-finite von Neumann algebra with a faithful normal semi-finite trace $\tau$. Let $T$ be a $\tau$- measurable operator (densely defined closed (possibly unbounded) operator affiliated with $\mathcal{M}$ such that
$$ \forall_{\varepsilon >0} \  \exists_{E - \text{a projection in} \text{M}} \  \mbox{Range}(E) \subset D(T) \ \& \ \tau(1-E) \leq \varepsilon.)$$

Let $E_{(s,\infty)}(|T|)$ be a spectral projection of $|T|$ corresponding to the interval $(s, \infty)$, $s \geq 0$.

How do we know that $\| |T|E_{(s,\infty)}(|T|) \| > s$ or  $\| |T|E_{[0,s]}(|T|) \|  \leq s$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "measurable operators"-- it just follows from the definition of the spectral projections...

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that because this is a part of the problem IX.2.7 in Takesaki vol. 2 and this problem concerns "measurable operators".
I can't see this from the definition of the spectral projection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Matthew said, this doesn't look like it has to do with measurability at all. Those two inequalities follow from the operator inequalities 
`\[
|T|\,E_{(s,\infty)}(|T|) \geq s\,E_{(s,\infty)}(|T|), \ \ \ 
|T|\,E_{[0,s]}(|T|) \leq s\,E_{[0,s]}(|T|).
\]`
In turn, these inequalities follow from the corresponding inequalities for real functions, 
`\[
t\,1_{(s,\infty)}(t) \geq s\,1_{(s,\infty)}(t), \ \ \ 
t\,1_{[0,s]}(t)\leq s\,1_{[0,s]}(t),
\]`
and the fact that functional calculus is positive.

Comment: It seems that $f$ is missing on the right hand side, isnt it?

Comment: That's for the observation, Tomasz. Actually, there was no need for $f$, so I've removed it. 

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I should give an answer, not just a comment.  The following maybe isn't the "correct" way to think about spectral projections, but I find that it helps my intuition.  Basically, if $T$ is a normal, possibly closed unbounded, operator on a Hilbert space $H$, then $H$ is unitarily equivalent to a measure space $L^2(\mu)$ and under this equivalence, $T$ is just a multiplication operator by a complex function $f$ (which is bounded if and only if $T$ is bounded).

If now $T$ is positive, then so is $f$.  The spectral projection $E_{(s,\infty)}(T)$ then corresponds to the projection given by the indicator function of the set $\{ x : f(x)>s \}$.  It's then clear that $T E_{(s,\infty)}(T)$ is multiplication by the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x)>s$, and $g(x)=0$ otherwise.  If $T$, and hence $f$, is unbounded, then so will be $g$.

Anyway, I find this mental picture of "it's just multiplication operators" to be handy when dealing with spectral stuff.  Martin's arguments are probably "cleaner" if you want a polished version...

Comment: Thank you for that, this is a really nice application of the spectral theorem. 